# I am getting the following error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input('enter no.'))
if (n % 2) != 0 or n > 6 and n < 20 == True:
print('weird')
else:
print('not weird')
```

if I run the above code, I get the above error.

Comment: Whatever you entered doesn't look like a number.

Comment: please also mention the input you tried

Comment: BTW, `n < 20 == True` is the same as `(n < 20) and (20 == True)` and I assume that is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is an indentation issue with this is what I can say, otherwise I am getting the perfect results.

Try this :

```
n = int(input('enter no.'))
if (n % 2) != 0 or n > 6 and n < 20 == True:
    print('weird')
else:
    print('not weird')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (n % 2) != 0 or n > 6 and n < 20:
   print('weird')
else:
   print('not weird')
```

Your original code was not properly indented.

Also, please check your logical criterion. It seems a bit weird.